# Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4: navbar with right aligned dropdown menu always visible / usable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good evening community, I'm a long time "lurker", I'd like to start off with a huge thank you to everyone for all your great information and hard work. I find myself faced with a little bit of a challenge / problem.

I'm trying to setup my primary navigation (navbar-default) to function as I desire on both desktop and mobile versions.

I want to setup a right side menu link which functions as a dropdown-menu however it is available on both the desktop and mobile versions of the website.

Here are some images of what I have in mind:

The desktop view has the logo on the far right, links beside that and the far right link (Link #3) has the dropdown-menu (see below):

[image]

Tablet/mobile width keeps the logo to the left, hides the the links #1 and #2 and still keeps the Link #3 dropdown-menu available with the menu toggle on the far right (see below):

[image]

When the menu is opened (hamburger clicked), it menu displays as normal and shows Links #1,#2.

Comment: Have you try to put the #Link3 outside navbar-default div with pull-right class ?

Comment: Hey MaGiO, yes I did try a combination of setups with pull-right and it wasn't working properly, the dropdown just didn't seem to want to function exactly how it does on the desktop version (non-collapsed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want make something [like this](http://codepen.io/MaGiO/pen/eNYaep)?

HTML

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mobileNav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.mobileNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0px;
} 
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { 
    .mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 90px;
        top: -2px;
    }
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    .mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 90px;
        top: -2px;
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  { 
    .mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 90px;
        top: -2px;
    }
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    .mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 90px;
        top: -2px;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE CODE:**

link update: http://codepen.io/MaGiO/pen/eNYaep

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>

                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mobileNav pull-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>
                </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.mobileNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mobileNav {
        position: absolute;
        right: 80px !important;
        top: 0px;
        width: 195px;
    text-align: right;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
        text-align: right;
        border: 1px solid #efefef;
    margin-top: 2px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:active,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
        background:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey MaGiO, thanks for the reply. Yes that is very close to what I am looking to accomplish, however using your codepen.io link it looks like the drop down is functioning differently in the desktop version than in the tablet/mobile version. The dropdown is overlapping the toggle button and when the dropdown is clicked it changes it's size to the full width of the dropdown-menu. Is it possible to correct these? Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: Yes is possible, i update the code in the afternoon. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much MaGiO, I look forward to it.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply MaGiO, thank you for your help and solution!

Comment: To get this to work for me i needed to add $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown(); Thank you!